# Optionally Select Columns from Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have written a function that takes a list of file-paths and then concatenates them into one large dataframe. I would like to include an argument that takes a list of column names the user is interested in looking at.

The dataframe must always contain the 'category' column if the user decides to filter the columns, but I want the default to be that it returns all of the columns. I can't quite seem to figure out how to optionally select columns from a dataframe.

Here is my function interspersed with some psuedo code to explain what I'm talking about.

```py
def combine_all_data(data_files, columns_needed=ALL):
    dataframes = map(pd.read_csv, data_files)

    if columns_needed != ALL
        columns_needed = ['category'] + columns_needed

    df = pd.concat(dataframes, sort=False)[columns_needed]
    return df
```

Comment: I don't follow what the issue is. What specifically is the problem you're facing?

Comment: We can't see `ALL` so presumably you get `'category'` added twice in some instances?

Comment: `category` is a column added behind the scenes that a user wouldn't really know about, so I'm not expecting it as input from the user. This is why always need to make sure category is there, but need to handle the cases where the user doesn't define a `columns_needed` (I can't return an empty dataframe)

Comment: `if 'category' not in columns_needed:`? If the specified list is `None`, add `ALL`. If it's not `None` but doesn't include `'categories'`, prepend `categories`. Otherwise, go with the list they gave. 3 possibilities, you cover only 2. Any alteration to the requested list of columns results in you prepending `category` to the list of columns. But that defeats the point of being able to drop other columns with no consequence

Comment: Btw. maybe you also need to specify `ignore_index=True` in the `concat` call in case the dataframes have regular integer index (most likely they have). Otherwise probably the result has duplicates in the result index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the `ALL` you don't know how to implement, you can try this:

```
def combine_all_data(data_files, columns_needed=None):
    kwargs= dict()
    if columns_needed is not None:
        if 'category' not in columns_needed:
            columns_needed= ['category'] + columns_needed
        kwargs['usecols']= columns_needed
    dataframes = [pd.read_csv(data_file, **kwargs) for data_file in data_files]
    return pd.concat(dataframes, sort=False)
```

The advantage of this is, that you need less memory, because the columns you don't want to see, are already skipped in the reading process.
Addtionally you return a full dataframe not a slice of one. So you can work with it without restrictions.

Comment: Thank you @roganjosh: I added it. I guess the result would have been duplicate columns.

Comment: It would have been, yes :)

Answer (score 2):

`read_csv` has a `usecols` argument:

```
def combine_all_data(data_files, columns_needed='ALL'):
   if needed_columns != 'ALL':
      if not 'category' in columns_needed:
         columns_needed.append('category')
      return pd.concat([pd.read_csv(x, usecols=columns_needed) for x 
      in data_files], sort=False)
   else: 
      return pd.concat([pd.read_csv(x) for x in data_files], sort=False)
```

Comment: You can't use single backticks for multi-line code to get the formatting correct. Highlight the whole chunk of code and use ctrl +k or click the `{}` button in the editor, or use triple backticks

Comment: We almost had the same idea. Btw. does `pd.read_csv(x, usecols='ALL')` really work? But otherwise you also only would have to translate it to `None` or whatever pandas uses as default for the keyword.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's just a string that could be anything really. The point is that if `columns_needed`  equals the default argument, the `else` statement is executed in which the `usecols` argument is not used.